# How to generate UML diagram from tables in SQL Server Object Explorer of Visual Studios?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, uml

In SQL Server Object Explorer, I see a list of tables under "Tables" under my database within the "Databases" directory. How do I automatically create a UML diagram of these tables. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you want to automatically generate them or create them by hand?

Comment: Automatically generated

Comment: Then correct the second sentence of the question, please.

Comment: While this is not a direct answer, you may want to look into this article from Phil Factor about generating PlantUML diagrams using SQL statements: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-tools/automatically-creating-uml-database-diagrams-for-sql-server/

Answer (score -1):

1. UML has no diagram for database content.
2. Classes from class diagram can be implemented as DB tables. They CAN model simple tables. But if you have a table with inner references, it could be modelled as one or several classes. And nobody except you can say exactly how many classes will be got from a table.
3. MS Visio has non-UML Database diagram. THEY have Table element and surely, can be generated from most of the DBs. Look [here](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Reverse-engineer-an-existing-database-into-a-database-model-fb034862-acfc-45bc-88b2-f33d1e1f8614?CorrelationId=b0fe6df3-c4fd-4436-9500-ae546b265a48&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US)